# TextBox in dynamic column doesn't wrap text

Tags: silverlight

I have a TextBox in a column with dynamic column:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

The width of TextBox just fit to users' screen. But when the text in it is longer than its initialized width, the TextBox will increase its width insteed of wrap text inside.

I can assign a static width to TextBox but it's ugly. Is there any way to make its width initialized dynamic but static in run time?

Comment: Can you show more of your XAML?

Comment: Current XAML can describe my problem: If a TextBox has no width nad doesn't inherit one, the TextWrapping dosn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this at this time. Wait for Silverlight 5 to fix this using Ancestor RelativeSource.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted so far looks fine to me.  A little test in Blend confirms the text wraps as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The construction as described works only when one of the parents limits the width of the visual elements. This is most likely not the case, but I can't see that from the XAML posted in the question.

The reason for the lack of limits on the width of the controls is most likely a scrollviewer at some level in the control tree that the described XAML is part of.